# Error while adding and removing plotLine on highcharts

Tags: highcharts

```
click: function() {
                          if (!hasPlotLine) {
                                chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
                                    value: 5.5,
                                    color: '#FF0000',
                                    width: 2,
                                    id: 'plot-line-1'
                                });

                            } else {
                                chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine('plot-line-1');
                            }
                            hasPlotLine = !hasPlotLine;
                    }
```

Am trying to add and remove the plot lines on click event and I ended up with this eeror "Cannot read property xAxis of undefined"

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FzNqA/5/)

Comment: Updated the Demo link; addPlotLine not plotting the line on chart!

Comment: Small modification to the question, is it possible to plotline on click event of chart? Not on the click event of plotoptions? http://jsfiddle.net/rGCX4/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume what you would like to remove "old" plotLine and add new in clicked x value. So first of all I recommend to remove conditions, and only use remove/add plotline.

http://jsfiddle.net/FzNqA/8/

```
click: function () {

                        var chart = this.series.chart.xAxis[0];


                            chart.removePlotLine('plot-line-1');
                            chart.addPlotLine({
                                value: this.x,
                                color: '#FF0000',
                                width: 2,
                                id: 'plot-line-1'
                            });
                    }
```

Comment: Is there any ways where in we can click in middle of the co-ordinates and place the marker? I meant in-between the two plotting points? Kind of sliding?

Comment: How can i do the same on page load without any user action ? I mean i wanted to do it based on a condition. What event shall fire it on load ?

Comment: You can add plotLines in the [load](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load) event